# Scheduling websolr reindexing using heroku scheduler

Tags: linux, django, heroku, django-haystack, websolr

I have a scheduled command in Heroku's Schedule app that is meant to rebuild websolr indexes.

```
heroku run python manage.py rebuild_index
```

The thing is that the command required input from the user so it never runs successfully automatically.

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N]
```

Is there any other way to rebuild my indexes using the Heroku Scheduler app or is there a way to automatically signal 'y' in the command so that the index is periodically built with my command in scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, adding the 'yes' command did the trick http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)

```
heroku run 'yes | python manage.py rebuild_index'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `--noinput` argument to the rebuild command, like this:

> heroku run python manage.py rebuild_index --noinput

See [Haystack management command documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/management_commands.html#rebuild-index) for more options.